# cant change type(danger,success) and add animated on vue strap

Tags: vue.js, vue-strap

i Want to make a progress bar using vue strap . i install vue strap on this link

[this link](https://wffranco.github.io/vue-strap/)

now i add a progress bar, this progress bar is showing , this bar is only showing color primary and cant showing animated .

```
 <template>
        <div class="progress">
            <progressbar now="99"  type="danger" striped animated ></progressbar>
        </div>
</template>

<script>
    import { progressbar } from 'vue-strap'

    export default {
        components: {
          progressbar
        },
        mounted() {
            console.log('Component mounted.')
        }
    }
</script>
```

with this code , this type is **primary** and this animated **didnt work** . 
i change browser from chrome to mozila , but its still didnt work . my browser is newest .

whats wrong about this ? i dont know why animated didnt work

Comment: This requires `bootstrap CSS` to work. Do you have it installed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a bug in VueStrap library when it comes to progress bar animations. The template for progress bar in VueStrap uses class `active` to animate, whereas, in Bootstrap 4 we have to use class `progress-bar-animated`. A work around of this problem is to created your own Progress Bar component which makes use of the Bootstrap 4.

Custom Progress Bar component could be written as:

```
Vue.component('c-progressbar', {
  template: `
    <div class="progress">
      <div class="progress-bar" :class="progressClasses"
          role="progressbar"  
          :style="progressStyle"></div>
    </div>`,
  props: {
    striped: Boolean,
    animated: Boolean,
    now: {
      type: Number,
      required: true
    },
    contextType: {
      type: String,
      default: 'primary'
    }
  },
  data: function() {
    let context = 'bg-' + this.contextType
    return {
      progressClasses: {
        'progress-bar-striped': this.striped,
        'progress-bar-animated': this.animated,
        [context]: true
      },
      progressStyle: {
        width: this.now + '%'
      }
    }
  }
})
new Vue({ el: '#app' })
```

You can use this pen for testing: https://codepen.io/abdullah-shabaz/pen/YzXdYgd

Comment: how if i use boostrap vue ? i try this but this animated still didnt work ?

Comment: how if i use boostrap vue ? i try this but this animated still didnt work ?

Comment: you just need to import bootstrap 4 and use this component. If it still doesn't work you can share some more details with me. Have you checked the pen I have made?

Comment: import { BootstrapVue, IconsPlugin } from 'bootstrap-vue'
import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css'
import 'bootstrap-vue/dist/bootstrap-vue.css'

// Install BootstrapVue
Vue.use(BootstrapVue);   all are added in app.js  ( use laravel)

Comment: so i create a new progressbar with boostrap but this problem is not solved , its just can change type (primary ,danger,success) this animated didnt work https://pastebin.com/EWZXQMxW

Comment: omg its solved , not watch on under i need at animated true , sorry sir